# Checking if an associated record exists in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have two tables in my PostgreSQL database named `users` and `businesses`. When a user logs in and accesses the `business/profile` I first want to check if they have actually created a profile. If not, I would then like to redirect them to the `business/create`. So basically, what I need to do is check whether the `businesses` table contains a record associated with the current user. I've tried a few things I thought would work but keep getting the following error:

```
Couldn't find User/Business without an id.
```

Currently my routes file contains the following definitions:

```
get "business/profile"
get "business/account"
get "business/create"

devise_for :users

get "home/index"
root :to => "home#index"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a relationship between User and Business model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :business
  end
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

in businees_controller.rb

```
class BusinessController < ApplicationController
 def profile
  redirect_to business_create_path unless current_user.business
  "your code"
 end
 def create
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're using `Business.find_by_...()` method, but it gives you 404 error if it does not find anything.

You should check it in this way:

```
def profile
  if current_user.businesses.count == 0
    redirect_to business_create_path
  else
    # ...
  end
end
```

I suppose that you have a User::belongs_to(Business) relation in your models.